# ServerSocket wont wait until it's closed to reopen

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am writing a client/server app in java, and I am trying to make the server capable of restarting itself. Currently, the server accepts a connection, reads an Object from the client, then passes the Object/Socket/Stream to a new Thread which takes over from there. This next part is the problem though: to restart the already running server (lets call this instance "instance 1"), I start a new instance of it (instance 2). If the ServerSocket is already in use, instance 2 should write a null to the ServerSocket which will cause instance 1 to close it, then instance 2 should just run the same block as before. Doing this successfully terminates instance 1, but unless I enter debug mode and control which line happens when, instance 2 tries to reopen the ServerSocket before it is closed, so it terminates as well. I cannot get instance 2 to wait until the ServerSocket is closed to try opening it again. Is there a method or implementation for this I just can't find?

```
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Tester {

    protected ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Tester();
    }

    public Tester () {
        try {
            listen();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4444);
                new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()).writeObject(null);
                socket.close();

                listen();
            } catch (Exception ex) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }

        return;
    }

    public void listen () throws Exception {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);) {
            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                Object obj = in.readObject();
                if(obj == null)
                    break;
          //    this.threadPool.execute(new ServerThread( ... ));
            }
            threadPool.shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to study the concept of multithreading, it'd help achieve what you want. Also, what you want to achieve is unclear.

Comment: That's true, but I'm pretty sure I at least know this part. My problem is I cant find any implementation for ServerSockets that lets me safely wait for instance 1 to close the ServerSocket before instance 2 opens it. What I want to achieve is to be able to just open another instance of the Server (Tester here) and it will close the previous instance then take over the port just like the old one. Eventually I'll add implementation to close the ServerSocket gracefully so we don't need to disconnect all the clients every time we want to restart the server.

Comment: Then how would you update your server? We need to be capable of updating the server on the fly without killing the Threads of the previous one. The Threads can take hours, so we can't just tell users on the client ends to stop using the Server until the Threads are done. This solution would let instance 1 of the server finish their old Threads, and lets the new and improved Instance 2 handle the new ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening the ServerSocket in a time-delayed loop, like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  Thread.sleep(2000); //select your sleep time
  try {
    reopenMyServerSocket();
    break;
  }
  catch (IOException iox) {}
}
```

Comment: That allows it to work, but that's just because you've tricked it into not really being a race condition anymore because instance 1 should take less than 6 seconds to close the socket, right? In actuality, this program is going to run on a server which is REEAAALLY slow, so I'm hesitant to just hard-code delays that the first instance should beat. It seems though like I should be able to swap the for-loop with a while-loop and the "break" with some flag to exit the while-loop. That would loop forever until the socket is opened again, right?

Answer (score 0):

Using threads would be a suitable way to handle this. If you want to use threads then you can follow my example.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        renderServer(9000);//render socket and handle request
    }

    public static void renderServer(int port){    
        ServerSocket  serverSocket  = new ServerSocket (port);
        System.out.println("Server started on "+ new Date());     

        while(true){
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept(); 

            HandleClient handleClient = new HandleClient(socket);
            Thread thread = new Thread(handleClient);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
```

Then you would have to create the HandleClient class that would handle each request. Note the the HandleClient class must implement Runnable as in the sample below.

```
public class HandleClient implements Runnable{ 

        Socket socket;

        public HandleClient(Socket socket){
            this.socket = socket;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Your code goes in here
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            //Then you can continue from here
        }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I actually already have a separate Thread class which does this. It works well though, so thank you for the suggestion! You're absolutely right. However, I'm having trouble with a different part. I'm trying to set up my server to restart a previous instance of itself. So when it starts up and sees its port is already in use (by the first instance), it sends a signal to it which the first instance interprets as a signal to shut down, then the new instance should take over the port.

Comment: Okay got you now. But that would be a difficult thing to do. The thread can handle several instances on that same port. You know that too as well. I dont know what you are trying to do but............

Comment: Cool, thanks! But I actually think I'm sticking with ControlAltDel's solution, just with a little tweak I'm adding in his comments. Still though, thanks for the help! This is a really, really good answer, just for a slightly different question. By the way, though, the problem was that the new instance of the server needs to be open on the same port as the previous instance, but we can't open two ServerSockets on one port. So we need to close the old version's, but in a way that we don't lose all the current clients' connections.